# Set background for d3.js collabsible tree

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I create a collabsible tree like in this example (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083). I tried to change the background color of the SVG. Therefor I use a "rect" element before inserting the "g" element:

```
svg = d3.select("#"+targetDIVName).append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.attr("id", "svg_graph")
.append("rect")
.attr("width", "100%")
.attr("height", "100%")
.attr("fill", "green") //for example
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

With this method the graph is hidden. Is there any solution to set the "rect" element as background and get the graph visible?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG elements are drawn in the order in which they are added. So if you want the `rect` to be in the background, add it as the first element after creating the SVG.

To get a solid background colour, you could alternatively use the [`viewport-fill` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#viewport-fill-property), which is not supported by all browsers though.